# robot framework - how to use the same name functions but come from different python library I created in Keywords section

Tags: python, robotframework

I have two python files which I want to import to robot framework.

They are:

**File_A.py**

```
class File_A(object):
     def func(self):
         print 'a'
```

**File_B.py**

```
class File_B(object):
     def func(self):
         print 'b'
```

I want to use them (the functions of the same name but come from different python library I created) in robot framework.

I tried:

```
***Settings***
Library  ../File_A.py  WITH NAME  A
Library  ../File_B.py  WITH NAME  B

***TestCases***
Test 
   Run

***Keywords***
Run
   A.func
   B.func
```

I want to get the printing results, but only one library is imported successfully. Appreciate for any help.

Comment: The way you show it in the question is how you do it. You say you get an import error, what was the error?

Comment: You have a typo in `***TestCases***` it should be `*** Test Cases ***`

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your code(I copied and did not change anything). There is no error on my side. 2 libs are imported successfully and called properly. Maybe something's wrong with your Python config?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me this work:

```
***Settings***
Library  ../File_A.py
Library  ../File_B.py

***TestCases***
Test 
   Run

***Keywords***
Run
   File_A.func
   File_B.func
```